# How to unlock user (customer, not admin) from database after entering wrong passwords?

Tags: magento-1.7

How can I unlock a user if he was locked after entering the wrong pasword too many times? I checked is_active in customer_entity, but its always 1, even for locked users. Whats the right place to to that in the database?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get any solution for unlock customer account? Please post answer here if any.

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking about admin users you can unlock them in `System \ Permissions \ Locked Users`.

Of cause you can also do it directly with a query like this:

```
UPDATE admin_user 
   SET failures_num = 0, lock_expires = NULL
 WHERE user_id = ?
```

Comment: No, I was talking about shop customers, not the admin users.

Answer (score 2):

I've found solution to unlock customer account from Database. Search `oauth_token_request_log` table in your Magento2 DB and find the customer email whose account you want to unlock, and delete the row.

It will unlock customer account.

Thanks